# Sub-directory domain on subdomain multisite?

Tags: multisite, directory, subdomains

Simple use case, having the possibility to have both sub-directory and subdomain domains on a multisite installation, e.g. `https://example.com/en` for another language.

The multisite installation itself is setup as a WordPress subdomain multisite.

How to have sub-directory domains on a subdomain multisite installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an answer on here. But [on the net](https://florianbrinkmann.com/3428/wordpress-multisite-subdomains-und-unterverzeichnisse/), it's in German. I thought I share it here, because it is a neat solution.

As suggested I added below cookie constants to the `wp-config.php`.

```
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
define( 'COOKIEPATH', '' );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', '' );
```

And replaced the content of the `.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

After this you can create a new site, with a random subdomain. Because you still can not directly create the new site as sub-directory domain. But you can go to the edit screen of the newly created domain, and there you change the URL to the sub-directory domain you want to have.

So far it works like a charm for me.